# Carrierwave / Fog / S3 "is not a recognized storage provider"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have a Rails app that is using Carrierwave for file uploads. It has been working fine but I want to start using Amazon S3 for my image storage. I am getting this error:

```
ArgumentError ( is not a recognized storage provider):
  app/controllers/salons_controller.rb:52:in `update'
```

I have made sure I have the latest gems for Carrierwave and Fog. This is in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'fog'
```

fog.rb looks like:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_credentials = {
        :provider              => 'AWS',
        :aws_access_key_id     => 'MYACCESSKEY',
        :aws_secret_access_key => 'MYSECRETKACCESSKEY',
        :region                => 'us-east-1'
    }

    config.fog_directory = 'andrunix'
    config.fog_public    = true
    config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
```

end

The Uploader class looks like:

```
class SalonImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    # "andrunix" is the bucket name on S3

    "andrunix/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

If I change the storage back to 'file', it works fine. Setting storage to 'fog' generates this error.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

OK, I'm an idiot. :)

At some point, I don't know where, I added a fog.rb file with my CarrierWave configuration to the lib/carrierwave/storage directory. I got desperate, paid for a Railscasts subscription so I could watch episode #383 (http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3?autoplay=true) and at 3:02 I found the error of my ways. The Carrierwave configuration needed to be placed in config/initializers/carrierwave.rb.

I don't know where I got this other location but once I moved the config to the proper location, everything is good.

Comment: You're not an idiot. I did the same thing! It's because of the ambiguous phrasing in the carrierwave readme (search for lib/carrierwave/storage).

Comment: I did the same thing. Carrierwave documentation lists `lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb` and doesn't specify the path you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem, and people must be aware that any typo in the config file : "config/initializers/carrierwave.rb", leads to that error.