# Rails Tutorial Chapter 11. Carrierwave and Cloudinary. Heroku application Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, carrierwave, cloudinary

I am following Rails Tutorial and do not use AWS because I do not have Credit Card.

So I tried using Cloudinary.

I am a complete noob here, I am not even sure whether it can be done.
The point is I want to deply my website on heroku and I can upload images.

It works fine via localhost but has this error on heroku:

```
No command 'run' found, did you mean:
 Command 'runq' from package 'sendmail-bin' (universe)
 Command 'runq' from package 'exim4-daemon-heavy' (main)
 Command 'runq' from package 'exim4-daemon-light' (main)
 Command 'rn' from package 'trn' (multiverse)
 Command 'rn' from package 'trn4' (multiverse)
 Command 'qrun' from package 'torque-client-x11' (universe)
 Command 'qrun' from package 'torque-client' (universe)
 Command 'srun' from package 'slurm-llnl' (universe)
 Command 'zrun' from package 'moreutils' (universe)
 Command 'grun' from package 'grun' (universe)
 Command 'rup' from package 'rstat-client' (universe)
run: command not found
budi@Lenovo:~/sample_app$ heroku run rake console
Running rake console on rocky-badlands-7040... up, run.6999
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'console'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
budi@Lenovo:~/sample_app$ heroku run rake console --trace
Running rake console --trace on rocky-badlands-7040... up, run.7578
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'console'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

my picture_uploader.rb

```
# encoding: utf-8

class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick

   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick
   process resize_to_limit: [400, 400]
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave


   # process :tags => ['post_picture']

#   version :standard do
#    process :resize_to_fill => [200, 300, :north]
#  end

#  version :thumbnail do
#    resize_to_fit(50,50)
#  end

#  def public_id
#    return model.short_name
#  end

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  if Rails.env.production?
    #storage :cloudinary
     storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end


  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  # end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
   def extension_white_list
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
  # def filename
  #   "something.jpg" if original_filename
  # end

end
```

via localhost, it works fine.
[image]

on heroku, it doesn't show at all.
[image]

heroku logs -t

```
budi@Lenovo:~/sample_app$ heroku logs -t
2016-01-21T12:10:52.739963+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2016-01-21T12:10:52.739964+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2016-01-21T12:10:52.739966+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2016-01-21T12:10:52.739967+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:107:in `app'
2016-01-21T12:10:52.739968+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:113:in `load_and_bind'
2016-01-21T12:10:52.739968+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cluster.rb:301:in `run'
2016-01-21T12:10:52.739970+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:512:in `run'
2016-01-21T12:10:52.739971+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2016-01-21T12:10:52.739972+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2016-01-21T12:10:52.739974+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
2016-01-21T12:10:53.552732+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-01-21T12:10:53.541907+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-01-21T12:11:13.076187+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-badlands-7040.herokuapp.com request_id=0cbb3342-7b1e-4bfa-8fd5-8b7073f4ea8b fwd="118.96.108.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-21T12:11:17.866525+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-badlands-7040.herokuapp.com request_id=d76107d2-5ca9-4bc2-b8eb-f4160e777161 fwd="118.96.108.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-21T12:17:35.810665+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-badlands-7040.herokuapp.com request_id=115145da-9cdb-4883-bcc0-ec00a176757a fwd="118.96.108.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-21T12:57:57.028909+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-01-21T12:57:59.871803+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2016-01-21T12:58:02.536102+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2016-01-21T12:58:02.536157+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Version 2.11.1 (ruby 2.0.0-p648), codename: Intrepid Squirrel
2016-01-21T12:58:02.536190+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2016-01-21T12:58:02.536225+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Environment: production
2016-01-21T12:58:02.536258+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Process workers: 2
2016-01-21T12:58:02.536292+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Preloading application
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277527+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:73:in `eval': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
2016-01-21T12:58:08.275816+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] ! Unable to load application: TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277534+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/configuration.rb:73:in `storage'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277536+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb:29:in `<class:PictureUploader>'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277536+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/uploaders/picture_uploader.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277537+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277538+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277538+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277539+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277539+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277540+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277540+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277541+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:526:in `load_missing_constant'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277541+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277542+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/micropost.rb:4:in `<class:Micropost>'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277544+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277549+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277546+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277546+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277544+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277548+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277543+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277545+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277547+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277549+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277550+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277543+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/micropost.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277551+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277551+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277552+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277553+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277553+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277554+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277554+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277555+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277556+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277556+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277557+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277561+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277561+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277562+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277563+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277563+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277564+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277565+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277566+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277566+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277567+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:in `new'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277567+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:in `<main>'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277568+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277569+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277569+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277570+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:107:in `app'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277571+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:113:in `load_and_bind'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277571+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cluster.rb:301:in `run'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277572+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:512:in `run'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277572+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277573+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2016-01-21T12:58:08.277574+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
2016-01-21T12:58:09.332125+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-01-21T12:58:09.347367+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-01-21T13:03:51.533641+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-badlands-7040.herokuapp.com request_id=64d84af0-fd70-4b8f-bf2b-4849cb0f8062 fwd="118.96.108.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-21T13:04:03.964797+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-badlands-7040.herokuapp.com request_id=6d8f88e0-d869-4e61-82a7-e2d31cc69f79 fwd="118.96.108.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-21T13:07:20.527352+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake console` by mulyantobudi26@yahoo.com
2016-01-21T13:07:23.429111+00:00 heroku[run.1056]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake console`
2016-01-21T13:07:23.412162+00:00 heroku[run.1056]: Awaiting client
2016-01-21T13:07:23.785983+00:00 heroku[run.1056]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-21T13:07:27.940357+00:00 heroku[run.1056]: Process exited with status 1
2016-01-21T13:07:27.974214+00:00 heroku[run.1056]: State changed from up to complete
2016-01-21T13:08:11.876711+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by mulyantobudi26@yahoo.com
2016-01-21T13:08:15.285484+00:00 heroku[run.8698]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2016-01-21T13:08:15.249919+00:00 heroku[run.8698]: Awaiting client
2016-01-21T13:08:15.660609+00:00 heroku[run.8698]: State changed from starting to up
2016-01-21T13:08:19.669455+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-badlands-7040.herokuapp.com request_id=dfad28a4-e6bf-4e70-9218-48dcf7bb950a fwd="118.96.108.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-01-21T13:08:23.018799+00:00 heroku[run.8698]: State changed from up to complete
2016-01-21T13:08:23.004693+00:00 heroku[run.8698]: Process exited with status 1
2016-01-21T13:16:44.227321+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rocky-badlands-7040.herokuapp.com request_id=a7c99802-285a-4b0b-9faf-b5cefb8a5526 fwd="118.96.108.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

---

EDIT

it shows now on heroku.

I added this

```
# Ignore uploaded test images.
/public/uploads
```

But, still have this error when I run 'heroku run rake db:seed'
This is not the complete log, just the error part. It shows at the end of the log.

```
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `at' for main:Object
/app/db/seeds.rb:28:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:547:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:250:in `load_seed'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:180:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

the website shows without micropost from the seed and  cannot upload images.
[image]

---

EDIT

the log when failed to upload an image file.

```
2016-01-21T14:27:46.690137+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (4.7ms)  INSERT INTO "microposts" ("content", "picture", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["content", "tbbt"], ["picture", "tbbt.jpg"], ["user_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-01-21 14:27:46.684003"], ["updated_at", "2016-01-21 14:27:46.684003"]]
2016-01-21T14:27:46.693068+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 313ms (ActiveRecord: 8.0ms)
2016-01-21T14:27:46.380264+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by MicropostsController#create as HTML
2016-01-21T14:27:46.380370+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"be6ZVkdmeCpsEXL3AkMrwH8oQAc3IMoBcemINp9pR0Iqn/O4GHpHtuoDeBjKJHd39Ybxi8oeS0jCI/cH3BMFPg==", "micropost"=>{"content"=>"tbbt", "picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fcad04cbc40 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160121-10-hcrp4r.jpg>, @original_filename="tbbt.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"micropost[picture]\"; filename=\"tbbt.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Post"}
2016-01-21T14:27:46.382705+00:00 app[web.1]:   User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
2016-01-21T14:27:46.682425+00:00 app[web.1]:    (1.0ms)  BEGIN
2016-01-21T14:27:46.691979+00:00 app[web.1]:    (0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
2016-01-21T14:27:46.694809+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-21T14:27:46.694811+00:00 app[web.1]: ArgumentError ( is not a recognized provider):
2016-01-21T14:27:46.694813+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/microposts_controller.rb:7:in `create'
2016-01-21T14:27:46.694813+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-21T14:27:46.694814+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-01-21T14:27:46.378030+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/microposts" for 118.96.108.186 at 2016-01-21 14:27:46 +0000
2016-01-21T14:27:46.697921+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/microposts" host=rocky-badlands-7040.herokuapp.com request_id=4539cf2e-302b-4c95-b01d-f6abe4bd27ce fwd="118.96.108.186" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2452ms status=500 bytes=1714
```

`

Comment: are you logged to Heroku at the same time ?

Comment: yes. should i not be logged on?
I mean, I open the heroku website as well with my account.

Answer (score 0):

Run `heroku run rails console` not `rake`

Comment: it show error as well. the error message is too long to be post here.lol

Comment: Have you deployed your application, with git push heroku master?

Comment: yes, I have doployed my apps. all deployment process went smoothly.

could you please check my picture_uploader.rb, if you don't mind..?

Comment: Could you run heroku logs -t, refresh the page on heroku, and paste the logs here

Comment: it is too long for comment, so I put it on my question above.

Comment: My guess would be that the include Cloudinary::Carrierwave sets the right storage, according to this https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/cloudinary/carrier_wave.rb#L11, and you are overriding it in the storage method. You should override it only in development

Comment: the website shows now in prodction but without microposts from database seed and I cannot upload images. I update my post above.

Comment: whats on /app/db/seeds.rb:28

Comment: wow..Thanks!! stupid me.lol

it was this `users = User.order(:created-at).take(6)`
while it should be this `users = User.order(:created_at).take(6)`

it runs on heroku now with the micropost, but still cannot upload images.

Comment: I put the log in my post above, it was the log when I tried to post an image file and the website show "We're sorry, but something went wrong...bla..bla..bla"

Comment: That's a carrierwave error, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16114957/carrierwave-fog-s3-is-not-a-recognized-storage-provider
I would recommend that you switch from file system to cloudinary on local machine, since its easier to debug. If you make it work locally it should work on heroku too

Comment: it seems that the link is specific for AWS. it might be oot, but I wonder. if I want to upload images into cloudinary server, what gems do I need? Do I still need fog, Carrierwave, and minimagick? That supposed to be enough, right?